# How to make dropdown with blur effect CSS

Tags: css, dropdown, navbar, bootstrap-5, blur

I tried to make my dropdown have the same opacity and same blur effect as my navbar, the opacity worked properly, but the blur effect didn't.

I heard that I have to use pseudo-class to achieve this, but I'm not sure to implement this.

```css
.navbar {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) !important;
        backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
      }
      .dropdown-menu {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) !important;
        backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
      }
```

```html
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top" style="">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
          aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a
                class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                href="#"
                role="button"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                Dropdown link
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <h1>Example Text</h1>
     <h1>Example Text</h1>
      <h1>Example Text</h1>
       <h1>Example Text</h1>
        <h1>Example Text</h1>
  </body>
```

As you can see, the dropdown doesn't have a blur effect, even though I already used !important;

Comment: The code you've posted is not sufficient to reproduce a UI that looks even remotely like your screenshot.  Please update your post with the full (CSS) code, and for bonus points format it as a [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) so that we can run it and see the same thing you are seeing, and then we will be happy to help you out!

Comment: Hi Jake, I already sent the Codepen, thank you in advance

Comment: We don't want to be sent to external platforms, where the content could change at any point in the future (which would then make this question lose context for people finding it later on.) A proper [mre] of your issue belongs _directly_ into your question.

Comment: Okay CBroe, do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get this result below.

```css
.navbar {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) !important;
        backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
      }
      .dropdown-menu {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) !important;
        backdrop-filter: blur(0);
      }
```

```html
<link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top" style="">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
          aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a
                class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                href="#"
                role="button"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                Dropdown link
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <h1>Example Text</h1>
     <h1>Example Text</h1>
      <h1>Example Text</h1>
       <h1>Example Text</h1>
        <h1>Example Text</h1>
  </body>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering, but what I want is that the dropdown to have a blur effect. Now I solved it with the help of :before in my css.

Comment: OK. is this answer correct? or  something else you are looking for?

Comment: No, because  the dropdown doesn't have blur effect, however I already found the solution using pseudo class. Thank you